# How can I find whether a given algebraic expresion T can be obtained as linear combination from a set S (with number coeficients)

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, polynomials

We might take:

```
s = {(x-y)^2, x*y+z};
e = (x+y)^2 + 4*z;
```

and `linearDecompose[e,s]` could give `{1,4}` for example.

I know `Solve` with universal quantifiers over all free variables would do it:

```
Solve[ForAll[{x,y,z},s.{q1,q2} == e], {q1,q2}]
```

But is this the "right" way to do it? Does it get inefficient in time and memory as the number of variables increases?

Is there a more specialized function for this purpose or will `Solve` work with high efficiency?

Comment: `In[19]:= SolveAlways[e == {c1, c2}.s, {x, y}]

Out[19]= {{c1 -> 1, c2 -> 4}}` So that's one way. Now `SolveAlways` is a bit dated and not the most efficient function in general, but it should do quite well when the underlying problem is linear, as this is.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = {(x - y)^2, x*y + z};
e = (x + y)^2 + 4*z;
```

You can also use [`PolynomialReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html):

```
{q, r} = PolynomialReduce[e, s, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 4}, 0}
> ```

```
e == q.s + r // Expand
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
ClearAll[linDecomp]
linDecomp = If[VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && #2 === 0, #, {}] & @@ 
    PolynomialReduce[##, Variables@#] &;

linDecomp[e, s]
```

> ```
>  {1, 4}
> ```

```
linDecomp[e, s + (x + y)^3]
```

> ```
>  {}
> ```

Comment: This is good but...in a "bad" case, one might add e.g. `(x+y)^3` to both polynomials in `s`. That would make for trouble.

Comment: why would that be?

Comment: It would fail to give the desired result because no division would take place.